Blender 4.2 Cycles will not use my GPU to render, only CPU
Within the preferences, I have my NVIDIA Geforce RTX 3090 selected, as well as Optix. I also have them both selected within the render settings, however, when I render anything Task Manager shows 100% CPU usage and 0%-1% GPU usage. Even if I switch to CUDA and monitor the CUDA usage from Task Manager, CPU is used and GPU remains at 0%-1% usage.

I think the Windows Task Manager is not the most reliable source for these informations. However, depending on how complex your scenes are, the CPU will be used a lot as well, because the CPU usually does a lot of the scene building and render preparations after you hit F12 before the actual GPU rendering begins. The other question is, have you enabled GPU Compute in the Render Properties or is it still on CPU? Because enabling it in the preferences alone is not enough. Another question: is there a difference in speed between CPU and GPU Compute? If so, then Blender uses the GPU.
